# Dynamics 365 CRM Plugin - Unable to set two option field NULL in managed solution

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, onload, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I have 2 environments: DEV & TEST. I want to achieve functionality as mentioned as below:

```
if (fields.email.getValue() == null) {
    fields.emailAllowed.setValue(null);
    fields.emailAllowed.setRequiredLevel("required");
}
else {
    fields.emailAllowed.setRequiredLevel("none");
}

if (fields.phone.getValue() == null) {
    fields.phoneAllowed.setValue(null);
    fields.phoneAllowed.setRequiredLevel("required");
}
else {
    fields.phoneAllowed.setRequiredLevel("none");
}
```

This JavaScript code is working fine in DEV environment but due to some unknown reason it is **NOT** saving the NULL value in TEST environment.

To support that, I have added a new CRM plugin in which I have created two handlers:

> Create Plugin ==> PreValidation
> Update Plugin ==> PreValidation

In both of these plugins, I am using logic as below:

```
// Gets PreImage & Target Image combined
public void Execute()
{
    var combinedTarget = GetCombinedTarget();

    if (combinedTarget == null)
    {
        // log & throw error
    }
    
    MapEmailField(combinedTarget);
    MapPhoneField(combinedTarget);
}

private void MapEmailField(combinedTarget)
{
    // if Email is NULL and EmailAllowed IS NULL
    if(combinedTarget.Metadata.Attributes.Email != null && combinedTarget.Metadata.Attributes.EmailAllowed == null)
    {
        //log & throw error
    }
    else if(combinedTarget.Metadata.Attributes.Email == null)
    {
        combinedTarget.Metadata.Attributes.EmailAllowed = null; // To save NULL value into CRM field
    }
}

// same method for phone field mapping

// save the record
```

Now in CRM UI, when I update email field, it automatically sets TRUE value to **Phone Allowed** field too, even though it is not changed and I have *externally set it NULL* in CRM plugin. And there are 5 more such fields are getting affected in same way.

The same changes are working fine in DEV environment but not in TEST environment.

NOTE: I have cross verified that all changes of DEV environment are moved into managed solution and it is there in TEST environment.

> UPDATE 1:
>
> > I tried today debugging the JavaScript change in **TEST** environment, and through that it updated the records correctly. But when I closed the debugger and test the same scenario with new record, it updated all records again!!
>
> UPDATE 2:
>
> > As my JavaScript function is getting called on onLoad event too so that it can set NULL value, but looks like it is not able to find the control or something and that's the reason it is working while debugging but not in regular mode.

Below is the Javascript function which gets executed onLoad event:

```
function handleAllowedFields(dataField, allowedField) {

    return function () {
        if (dataField == null || allowedField == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (dataField.getValue() == null) {
            allowedField.setValue(null);
            allowedField.setRequiredLevel("none");
            allowedField.controls.forEach(function (c) {
                c.setDisabled(true);
            });
        } else {
            // If dataField is having a value, then contact preference fields
            // can have an value as Allow OR DoNotAllow ONLY.
            allowedField.controls.forEach(function (c) {
                c.setDisabled(false);
            });
            allowedField.setRequiredLevel("required");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help that how can I make my function to wait till all controls gets loaded on the form in onLoad event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

It's true that Managed solution was unable to save the NULL value for `two option type` field. While it was able to do that in unmanaged solution.

Alongside with that, I found that onLoad event was not executed after onSave event in JavaScript and this was the reason behind the issue.

Hence, what I did as a solution is I added an onChange event to `modifiedon` field on the form and it is working like butter.

P.S.: I'm not using `OptionSet` instead of `TwoOptionSet` field is so that the default fields gets utilised properly by the customer for every other built in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As you aware, CRM Two options is not good enough to store NULL or treat it as a NULL-able boolean field. Either have a global or local optionset (this allows NULL) with two values - this will allow to start the record with a NULL value & no need of javascript or plugin to massage the data every time.

Anyway script will not trigger when data import happens or anything outside the platform like web api calls - so plugin is good choice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. Even I went for optionset field only  but as suggested by my senior, I had to try with TWO OPTION set. And btw, fyi, in managed solution (dev environment) environment I'm able to store the NULL value. But it's behaving strange in managed solution.

Comment: And also, in this perticular scenario, I need to make sure that if user is having the data field (e.g. Email) then there has to be value (not null) in allowed field(email allowed). So if I do use option set I need to set additional check that value should not be null.

Comment: @PratikSoni I'm also curious why this is not consistent between environments & is the Managed solution is the only reason behind it..

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having the same question. :) Even I'm curious to know that can this be the aTwo Option set datatype? Can there be any other scenario that I'm missing here? And we are trying max to use the default fields of solution more - which is of two option set - so that we can utilize other functionality associated with these fields without any additional changes.